# Activate u8 literal in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, literals

How I can use `u8` literal in C++, using Visual Studio 2013 tool?

I have tried this: `string test = u8"áááá";` but it gives me the error that `u8 is undefined`. I have C++ v.11

Comment: Are you sure you're in C++11 mode when compiling?

Comment: I think yes. How I can test the version to be sure?

Comment: @tadman: Visual Studio doesn't have "modes" like that, as far as I'm aware. You get what you're given, basically.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Fair enough. I've never had to go poking around at switches within it, but most compilers have a zillion of them and I know Xcode takes a little coaching to get everything 100% lined up. Does Visual Studio 2017 deal with this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VS2013 doesn't support Unicode string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). If you want them, you need to update to VS2015.

You may also want to use actual C++ `string` literals (e.g. `u8"áááá"s`), not mere C-style-string literals (e.g. `u8"áááá"`), which [VS2015 supports so long as you include the necessary `using namespace` for them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
```

Comment: wtf: `std::string_literals` is responsible for operator""s ("hi"s -> `std::string`) not `u8`

Comment: @fnc12: True. I conflated the two features, where the `using` isn't needed if you keep using C-style literals. I've edited to correct that (it's still a good idea to use the literals for other reasons, e.g. avoiding runtime scans for `NUL` when the compiler knows the string length already, so I left the suggestion in).

Answer (score 3):

> I have C++ v.11

Mmm... not so much, no.

[Visual Studio 2013 does not support Unicode string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

You will have to upgrade your toolchain if you wish to use this C++11 feature.

Comment: That's it. I was thinking that is supports. Do you know how I can "replace" u8, to use it like, in VS 2013?

Comment: @GrandTim: Nope. You'll have to build up an array of `char` by hand with individual characters identified byte-by-byte!

Comment: @GrandTim: Without it, you're stuck using escapes for the individual bytes in the string, or making a wide char literal and encoding it to UTF-8.